# Rounding Calculated fields in Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I'm hoping that this is a fairly simple solution, but I'm fairly new to Dynamics 365 development and the documentation and prior questions I've seen so far haven't been too helpful.

I need to create a specifically rounded calculated field within an entity. Currently the field has been set up as a decimal type and I have the precision value set to 0 to produce a whole number.

The calculation I am currently using in the field calculation editor is simply `x + y / 100`. However whatever result comes from that needs to be always rounded up to the next whole number rather than the nearest one. Is there a way to force the field logic to always round upwards?

If a direct answer isn't available, any resources would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say it is working as expected since less than `0.5` will round off to lower nearest number (floor) and greater than `0.5` will round off to higher nearest number (ceiling).

To handle your scenario, to always round off to higher nearest number (ceiling) - I may recommend this: Add `49` like `(x + y + 49)/100`, in other words `0.49` to formula. This quirk came from top of my head but this may be the best option in calculated field perspective.

[image]

Comment: Perfect, this seems to be giving me the desired effect when tested. Thank you for your help.